# Pycharm (or Aptana Studio 3) and git pre-commit hook

Tags: django, git, ide, githooks

I have a **pre-commit** hook in my project - just for not commiting broken code:

```
python manage.py test some_app
```

It works okay from command prompt, but not from IDE's (not PyCharm, nor Aptana Studio 3).

What setting do I need to setup to make IDE work with hooks?

**update:** I tried latest versions of PyCharm - it does support git hooks.

Comment: In yhe pop up you get while doing a commit (Ctrl + K) you will have an option `Before Commit > Run Git hooks`. If `Run Git hooks` is not checked it will ignore any git hooks by default.